# Add hours together using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that displays the total number of regular hours and overtime hours in excel. I am trying to figure out how to add them together to get a Total hours worked in a month the excel sheet looks like the following

```
E00XXXX   James Smith     160:00   19:52
E00XXXX   John Doe        160:00   19:52
E00XXXX   Sue Patterson   160:00   19:52
```

I am trying to add the last two columns together to get something like this

```
E00XXXX   James Smith     160:00   19:52   179:52
E00XXXX   John Doe        160:00   15:22   175:22
E00XXXX   Sue Patterson   160:00   10:47   170:47
```

I don't have any code to try, because I honestly don't even know where to start. I would also like to state that this has to be done within a VBA and that I do not have control over the format in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically format times that when added together exceed 24 hours, 60 minutes, or 60 seconds, you can use the following custom number formats and the `SUM` function in Excel:

```
Hours = [h]:mm:ss
Minutes = [m]:ss
Seconds = [ss]
```

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266691)

Comment: Updated my question: I don't have control over the format of the excel sheet, only what is within the VBA macro, is there a way to change the format of a cell in VBA?

Comment: Yes - have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265350/how-to-change-format-of-a-cell-to-text-using-vba