# Set a String Value in a cell adn avoid it missinterpreted as a US date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a code as simple as:

```
Cells(1,1).Value="10/02/2018"
```

and I want cell A1 to have a value of **10/02/2018** either as Text or Date, but Excel is stupid enough to write **02/10/2018** in cell A1.

Besides cursing Excel programmers, how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Set the cell format to text first (`Cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "@"`), or set the cell format to the desired date format that will result in what you're looking for.  If that's October 2, 2018, the format would be `mm/dd/yyyy` but if it's 10th of February, 2018, the format would be `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Format of a Cell to Text using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265350/how-to-change-format-of-a-cell-to-text-using-vba)

Comment: Alternately, you could put an apostrophe at the beginning of the cell contents and that will also have Excel treat it like text: `Cells(1, 1).Value = "'10/02/2018"`

Comment: Just a note: Saving a date as text in the suggested format is the **worst** of all ideas. Because if you do that neither the computer nor a human can say if the date is actually `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`. Happy guessing then :) Since globalization the only recommendable text format can be `YYYY-MM-DD` ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

Answer (score 2):

So which date format do you want? `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`?

You can change it by using

```
Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
```

And you can write a proper date like

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = DateSerial(2018, 2, 10) 'DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)
```

Nevertheless I highly recommend to use the [ISO 8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) `YYYY-MM-DD` which is the only one that cannot be misinterpreted by humans.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a date, format the cell as 'mm/dd/yyyy' after inserting the value:

```
Cells(1,1).Value="10/02/2018"
cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

If you want it as Text then format the cell as text before inserting the value:

```
cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "@"
Cells(1,1).Value="10/02/2018"
```